# Linejoin for fat lines?

Tags: geometry, coordinate-systems, geometric-construction, rectangles

I draw a figure with 2 fat lines.
[image]

I need to draw a join between these lines correctly. Long red lines are in a middle of each fat line.

What I know:

- coordinates of white points.
- the angle between these 2 fat lines could be different, from 0 to Pi (not always Pi/2), but the thickness of these lines is always the same.
- Red lines are not drawn.

I need to find coordinates of a black point. How to solve this mathematical problem?

**Edited**

Solution with vectors is incorrect or I haven't understood it:

[image]

It shows what I currently have with vector addition. Blue lines means the solution I want to achieve and their intersection is the same as black point from a previous picture

Comment: If you know the white vertices of the "cross" and the respective lines are parallel, then try [vector addition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_vector#Addition_and_subtraction).

Comment: The remaining problem is the following. For example if I use this picture then I don't know where are the necessary point: in right top area or in left bottom.

Comment: First, you need to define which point you want to have. Given the picture, you can pick, but in general situation it might be the other one. If you do that, then the solution will follow immediately.

Comment: I have edited the question according to a code I currently have. I choose a necessary point from 2 ones with the following method. The vector which starts in fat line intersection point and ends in black point divides the angle between lines by 2. So I need to check if the half of an angle is a sharp angle or not.
But I still can't find a correct black point coordinates

Comment: From your picture it was not clear how the points were defined. Vector addition would work, when you would also have a vector that is parallel to your fat lines and has appropriate length (as it was on the first picture). If you define vectors by "perpendicular" edges of your fat lines, then you need a bit of trigonometry, i.e. the total length of blue fragment (the last diagram) is $2d\tan(\alpha/2)$, where $d$ is the length of the arrows and $\alpha$ is the angle in-between.

Comment: First, I wrote that fat lines may intersect with angle from 0 to Pi (not Pi/2 only or 90 degrees). I don't need the length of blue fragments. I drew them to show that the solution with vector addition is not correct. I still need the one point.

Comment: First, it would be great if you would start thinking on your own instead of demanding a full-fledged solution given on a silver platter for your convenience. Second, as for "I don't need", surely, there are many other ways to solve your problem, however, the length of single blue segment is the length of the missing vector you want to add to one of the arrows to obtain the desired point (it is parallel to your fat lines and perpendicular to the arrows). Third, if you would have some more (sensible) questions, I might try to answer them, but don't expect me to do it infinitely many times.

Comment: When I need to solve a difficult problem I try to solve it by myself. If I can't find a solution during a defined amount of time then I post its definition on stackoverflow (or similar). But I still try to solve it.

Comment: Can you say a little more about your method? I think I have solved this problem via finding black point as an intersection of 2 lines. But sometimes this point is too far from these lines. So I want to check my solution

Comment: Very small angles (or very close to $\pi$, depending what do you measure) may cause the black point to be arbitrarily far from your lines. I'll write more later.

Comment: I think I shouldn't round these numbers until I'll implement miterlimit (it cuts the line if it is longer than a specified value).